# PHP is Making Empty Rows in Database

Tags: php, html

So right now I've been noticing my php has been generating empty rows. And this is really annoying because I want to display the things on my website.
This is my submit:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" name="title" required>

<input type="text" placeholder="Author of Project" id="leader" name="leader" required>

<input type="text" placeholder="Number of Project Members" id="members" name="members" >


<input type="text" placeholder="Create 50 Character Summary" id="summary" name="summary" maxlength="50" required>

<textarea rows="10" placeholder="Create Detailed Paragraph on What Your Project is" id="paragraph" name="paragraph" required></textarea>


<input type="text" placeholder="$Money Goal" id="goal" name="goal" required>

<input type="date" placeholder="Date to Finish Goal" id="date" name="date" required>


<select name="location" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your State</option>
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
<option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
<option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
<option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
<option value="California">California</option>
<option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
<option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
<option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
<option value="District Of Columbia">District Of Columbia</option>
<option value="Florida">Florida</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
<option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
<option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
<option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
<option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
<option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
<option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
<option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
<option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
<option value="Maine">Maine</option>
<option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
<option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
<option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
<option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
<option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
<option value="Montana">Montana</option>
<option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
<option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
<option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
<option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
<option value="New York">New York</option>
<option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
<option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
<option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
<option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
<option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
<option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
<option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
<option value="Texas">Texas</option>
<option value="Utah">Utah</option>
<option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
<option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
<option value="Washington">Washington</option>
<option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
<option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select>                           
<center><p>Upload Image</p></center><input type="file" 
name="fileToUpload"id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*">
<div class="clearfix">
<button class="button1" type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Me Up</button>
</div>
```

And this is my PHP

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";


$title = $_POST['title'];
$leader = $_POST['leader'];
$members = $_POST['members'];
$summary = $_POST['summary'];
$paragraph = $_SESSION["paragraph"];
$goal = $_POST['goal'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$contact = $_SESSION["email"];
$fileToUpload= $_POST['fileToUpload'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
"jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed. ";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been 
uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO projects 
(title,summary,paragraph,leader,members,goal,date,location,contact, picture)
VALUES ('$title', '$summary', '$paragraph', '$leader', '$members', '$goal', 
 '$date', '$location', '$contact', '$fileToUpload')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo " Project Created Successfully";
//echo '<script> location.replace("index.php"); </script>';
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Please help me because this is extremely annoying.

Comment: PHP isn't making extra rows in your database, you are. Also your code is very open to SQL injection, like VERY.

Comment: Before inserting , try to check if the from is submitted.